# Multiple NSArray enumeration

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsarray, enumeration

Let's say I have three arrays of same size. I have to do something with all objects. If I would use a standard C array, I would write something like

```
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    doSomething(array1[i]);   // or [[array1 objectAtIndex:i] doSomething];
    doSomethingElse(array2[i]);   // or [[array2 objectAtIndex:i] doSomethingElse];
    doSomethingReallySpecial(array3[i]);   // or [[array3 objectAtIndex:i] doSomethingReallySpecial];
}
```

With Objective C we got more ways to cycle through objects in NSArray: fast enumeration, block-based enumeration and using enumerators. Which one should I use and why? What's the difference?

**Edit**
Actually this question may be formulated like this: if one needs to use the index of an item of an array, which enumeration should be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the one that most clearly expresses the intent of your code to readers of the code. Unless you have identified this loops as a significant performance bottleneck, ability to maintain your code is far more important.

That said, fast enumeration alone (i.e `for(id i in array)`) does not provide the index. If you don't want to use a C-style loop, `-[NSArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:]` provides both the current item and the index and could be used to zip multiple arrays. I suspect, that for multiple arrays, the C-style approach will be often be effectively equivalent in performance—and perhaps clearer to the reader, but you should profile it to be sure.

What you're looking for is a common idiom in functional programming and could certainly be implemented on top of GCD using blocks, but I don't know of any implementations.

Answer (score 4):

NSEnumerator-based methods were once the only supported way to enumerate. I can't think of any advantages it has over the others - it's slower and more unwieldy and has largely been superseded by the other methods.

Using blocks allows a lot flexibility. A method could accept a block as argument and use that to enumerate over several different collections:

```
- (void) doSomethingToFruits:(void(^)(id,NSUInteger,BOOL*))block
{
    [apples enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:block];
    [bananas enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:block];
    [kiwis enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:block];
}
```

You can also use the options argument in `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:options:` to enumerate over contents concurrently,.

Something I like about fast enumeration is that the NSFastEnumeration protocol allows me to add a method that accepts either arrays or sets, (or hashtables or whatever) but still has static type checking on the argument:

```
- (void) addObjectsFromCollection:(id<NSFastEnumeration>)coll
{
    for (id obj in coll) [self addObject:obj];
}
```

Otherwise, the syntax of the two just seem to fit better in different contexts. I find that if the main body of a method is enumerating over a collection it's clearer what is going on if I use fast enumeration, whereas if I just want to perform one or two actions on all contents in the middle of a larger method, blocks are more concise, but I guess this part is down to personal preference.

**Addendum:**

If you want to keep track of the index, the block option accepts an index as argument.